# Routing in container not working properly

Tags: linux, docker, networking, routes

Pinging a system in the internet works:

```
root@553c9e5ce5ea:/# ping -c 1 8.8.8.8      
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=9.61 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 9.619/9.619/9.619/0.000 ms
```

Pinging a system in the internal (corporate) network, does not work:

```
root@553c9e5ce5ea:/# ping -c 1 10.97.179.110
PING 10.97.179.110 (10.97.179.110) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 10.97.179.110 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

The routing in the container is straightforward:

```
root@553c9e5ce5ea:/# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.17.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Pinging the same system from the docker host is working fine:

```
host » ping -c 1 10.97.179.110  
PING 10.97.179.110 (10.97.179.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.97.179.110: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=4.70 ms

--- 10.97.179.110 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.703/4.703/4.703/0.000 ms
```

The system is reachable via a `vpn` interface in the docker host:

```
host » route -n | grep '^10\.'
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.248.0.0     U     0      0        0 tunsnx
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.252.0.0     U     0      0        0 tunsnx
10.12.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.254.0.0     U     0      0        0 tunsnx
10.14.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 tunsnx
10.15.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 tunsnx
10.15.20.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 tunsnx
10.15.24.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     0      0        0 tunsnx
10.15.32.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.224.0   U     0      0        0 tunsnx
10.15.64.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.192.0   U     0      0        0 tunsnx
10.15.113.108   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tunsnx
10.15.128.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.128.0   U     0      0        0 tunsnx
10.16.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.240.0.0     U     0      0        0 tunsnx
10.32.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.224.0.0     U     0      0        0 tunsnx
10.64.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.192.0.0     U     0      0        0 tunsnx
10.128.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.128.0.0     U     0      0        0 tunsnx
```

Why is the host not properly routing the traffic coming from the docker container?

### EDIT

I have been checking the IP tables counters, and this is what I see after `ping -c 100` (a host on the VPN):

```
» sudo iptables -x -v --line-numbers -L FORWARD | head
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num      pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1         100     8400 DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
2           0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3           0        0 DOCKER     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
4         100     8400 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
5           0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
6           0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    br-ad32be160e27  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
7           0        0 DOCKER     all  --  any    br-ad32be160e27  anywhere             anywhere            
8           0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  br-ad32be160e27 !br-ad32be160e27  anywhere             anywhere
```

Pinging a host on the internet (`8.8.8.8`) gives this:

```
» sudo iptables -x -v --line-numbers -L FORWARD | head
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num      pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1         200    16800 DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
2         100     8400 ACCEPT     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3           0        0 DOCKER     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
4         100     8400 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
5           0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
6           0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    br-ad32be160e27  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
7           0        0 DOCKER     all  --  any    br-ad32be160e27  anywhere             anywhere            
8           0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  br-ad32be160e27 !br-ad32be160e27  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: Just to experiment. Try with `--network host` in the docker run params.

Comment: @Robert Thanks. I tried, and with it works, but that is not a solution to my problem, since `--network host` conflicts with other settings

Comment: Are you running in either Windows or Mac? Did the VPN start after the docker daemon?

Comment: @BMitch under linux. The VPN was started after the docker daemon, indeed. But I do not see why that would make any difference ...

Comment: Try restarting your docker daemon, there's a lot happening under the covers with routing between the containers and outside networking to get all the NAT rules and port forwarding working.

Comment: @BMitch even restarting the docker daemon while the VPN is up and running does not allow a newly started container to reach the hosts in the VPN

Comment: Created [bug report](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/288)

Comment: Could you do a `tcpdump -nn -i your_vpn_interface icmp` while pinging 10.97.179.110 from the container and paste the output? If empty, you could retry with `tcpdump -nn -e -i any icmp`.

Comment: Is IPv4 forwarding enabled? `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as nothing related to programming. You should try SuperUser or ServerFault instead.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this @dangonfast